# Need clarification angularJs's forEach method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am new to angular js, and I was trying to get unique values using ng-repeat. I went through many sites for the example , one of them is [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/ThunderHemlock/bvsvzrr5/1/)

which I got from stackoverflow only. 
var app = angular.module('app', []);

```
app.filter('unique', function() {
return function(collection, keyname) {
  var output = [], 
      keys = [];

  angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];
      if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
          keys.push(key);
          output.push(item);
      }
  });
  return output;
};
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.items = [
  { id : 1,column : "col1", comment : "col1-label1",
    text1 : "col1-label1-text1",
    checked: false,

  },
  {
    id : 2,
    column : "col1",
    comment : "col1-label2",
    text1 : "col1-label2-text1",
    checked: false,

  },
  {
    id : 3,
    column : "col2",
    comment : "col2-label1",
    text1 : "col2-label1-text1",
    checked: false,

  },
  {
    id : 4,
    column : "col2",
    comment : "col2-label2",
    text1 : "col2-label2-text1",
    checked: false,

  },
  {
    id : 5,
    column : "col3",
    comment : "col3-label1",
    text1 : "col3-label1-text1",
    checked: false,

  },
  {
    id : 6,
    column : "col3",
    comment : "col3-label2",
    text1 : "col3-label2-text1",
    checked: false,

  },
  {
    id : 7,
    column : "col4",
    comment : "col4-label1",
    text1 : "col4-label1-text1",
    checked: false,

  },
  {
    id : 8,
    column : "col4",
    comment : "col4-label2",
    text1 : "col4-label2-text1",
    checked: false,

  }
  ];
});
```

But I am  having problem to understand at one point that I have spent hours on but still couldn't understand.

```
  **angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];**
In forEach method in the function we pass value , index and then the object itself that we are iterating over, In the above example we are only passing the value as "item" , then in the next line we are using as object/array. I am really confused, what is it? what are they trrying to do
```

Comment: What is your question? What don't you understand about forEach?

Comment: question is forEach's function takes value , index and then the object itself as parameters , now as item is the only parameter so this is value then how are we using as an array item[keyname] ???

Comment: Because keyname is coming from here `return function(collection, keyname) {`
which is above the foreach

Comment: keyname is not an issue , what about item ???

Comment: item is the "value" of the current position in the collection.

Comment: and that value is an object and hence we are able to do like item[keyname]  , had the value been a number we wodln't have done it, right ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142007/discussion-between-yepme-and-gforce301).